# Can cart drawer page be refreshed or reloaded? I have added 15 min timer code it displays but works only when I refresh the page?

Tags: shopify, cart, drawer, tabslideout

Can cart drawer page be refreshed or reloaded for certain event if so please help me? I have added 15 min timer code it displays but works only when I refresh the page?

Comment: can you share which certain events, so we can help you with that